# What does `==` do in zsh expansion?

Tags: zsh

I came upon this code:

```
map () {
    eval "$initDocs"
    usage "<lambda-function> [<item>...]"
    example "'<--- \$1 --->'" a b c d
    eval "$doneDocs"
    typeset f="$1"
    shift
    map_ () {
        echo ${(e)==f}
    }
    eval "$loopNow" map_
}
```

I do not understand what is the difference between `${(e)f}` and `${(e)==f}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `zshexpn(1)`:

```
${=spec}

    Perform word splitting using the rules for SH_WORD_SPLIT during the
    evaluation of spec, but regardless of whether the parameter appears
    in double quotes; if the `=' is doubled, turn it off.
```

In other words, specifying `${==f}` explicitly turns off `SH_WORD_SPLIT` for this single expansion, regardless of whether it is active globally.